# Vaadin Label CSS

Tags: java, label, vaadin

I want to apply CSS for Vaadin 23 label but its not working properly. Please suggest me appropriate process.

```java
Label label1 = new Label("Temp");
label1.addClassName("bold-label");
```

`vaadin-label.css`:

```css
:host(.bold-label) [part~="label"] {
    font-weight: bold;
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`Label` is standard HTML element. See [Mozilla Developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Not a specific Vaadin crafted component with [shadow DOM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_DOM) (where you would need the vaadin-*.css in the components folder).

Instead you can put your css inside `styles.css` and use a simple `label.bold-label` selector.